# How to create static fields dynamically in C# from a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, field

I am using dotnet standard 2.1

I have a list of strings that I would like to create into static class fields.

Below is a simplified example:

List:
`["chicken", "cow", "rooster"]`

I would class to set these fields on class Animal to the string value and look like below"

Ex:

```
    class Animal
    {
        public static string chicken = "chicken";
        public static string cow = "cow";
        public static string rooster = "rooster";
    }
```

I have tried to find a way to do something like below:

```
    class Animal
    {
        static Animal()
        {
            List<string> animals = new List<string>() { "chicken", "cow", "rooster" };
    // The above in practice will look like: List<string> animals = externalService.GetAnimals(); 

            foreach (var animal in animals)
            {
                Animal.setField(animal, animal);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried using Dynamic object but I would have to create an instance of a class. I want Animal to have these fields and be recognized by intellisense. So in VS, I would like to be able to call Animal.chicken.

Comment: You might have a use case for "source generators"

Comment: How about using an Enum for that purpose ?

Comment: @Julien I think I fall into the same scenario with an Enum don't I?

Comment: Although I actually think an enum is a viable answer for the minimal explanation you gave. But - what is your use-case for it, why do you "need it" like above?

Comment: Per @Crowcoder's answer, a source generator might be the only wah for you to leverage intellisense. I just thought generating an enum would be easier than having to go through static fields in a class, etc.

Comment: The above scenario is just a simplified version of what I would like to do, but it's all that is really necessary to explain the problem.

I could go an Enum route but I think I'd rather have the string values rather than the property be tied to an int

Comment: Why though? What actual problem are you trying to solve? Do you need both the list and `a.b` syntax at runtime?

Comment: Also, can you use a source generator for dot net standard 2.1? I'm not sure how that would look to be honest

Comment: @JeremyLakeman This list will be populated from a function and the values will be unknown.

Comment: The list of values must be known somewhere at compile time, since the only reason to generate fields is so you can write code which uses them. If the list changes, your other code will fail to compile. So I still fail to see why you would wish to generate these fields at compile time.

Comment: I'm reading the values from a datasource and then would like to create them into fields.

This is so I can dynamically create fields and alter what fields there are in my data source, not in my code.

Comment: could look into this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=netcore-2.1